Creating dockerfile image on macOS sequoia 15 using podman
I recently switched to new (M3 arm64) mac from windows and I am trying to run my old configs. On windows pc I had docker installed on ubuntu and was logging to daemon through intellijIdea plugin.
Here on Mac I downloaded podman and created symlink from podman to docker so I can access docker commands without sudo from bash.
I have a problem with running intellijIdea config for docker. It says its connected to daemon and correctly does every step in dockerfile however at the end of run I receive this error Failed to deploy ' Dockerfile:
--> 7ad3f942c461

STEP 11/11: EXPOSE 9080 9443

COMMIT project

--> 1d8b908ffb85

Successfully tagged localhost/project:latest

1d8b908ffb850921f8f1a122906f950194134d40fb1a22bca2723ccdfa3e6da3

Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile:/Users/peter/Documents/Github/Project/Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream

I believe the ID before error is the one it cant retrieve...
In dockerfile earlier I had to change FROM java--version because there was no option for arm64 chips
BEFORE
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine

NOW
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk

I am not sure if thats correct but it got me further to another error so I kept it there.
I am able to create the image from BASH using this
podman build -f Dockerfile -t project:latest

Then from podman desktop I am able to create container from image I created in BASH but i need to specify env variables every time and its pretty annoying. Especially when I need to restart it more often (you need to prune every container, then prune image, then run command from bash, then setup envVars and then create container)
I am used to run this approach
Here on windows I was able to recreate image open container and start service by one click.
Is there maybe some other windows to Mac options i forgot about or anyone has any experience with migrating from intel based chip to arm64 ? IDK smthing like classpath or anything i could not know as windows user.
Thank you for all answers

This could be totally unrelated, but there's been a number of issues with OSX 15 Sequoia related to firewall rules. Try running this:
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --listapps
I noticed that after upgrading to OSX 15, that command produced 15 entries (instead of zero), one of which was:
/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app: (Block incoming connections)
You can use that same command to modify the firewall rules.

I found intellijIdea there but as allow incoming connections.. I also granted full disk access to the IDE but thx for this .. might come handy
